# Accessing current DomainContext from Entity on client side

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I'm extending a partial class that was generated from an Entity Framework domain service (it inherits from `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity`).

In a property in this class, I want to be able to access a complete entity set from my DomainContext and run a query on it.

From within the `* : Entity` class, is there any good way to access the current `DomainContext`-derived object in order to get its entity sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ColinBlair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181921/colin-blair) says it currently [can't be done](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/197873.aspx).